# PHP HTML Mail Not Showing Image on Gmail

Tags: php, html-email

I am using this code to send an HTML mail by PHP

```
  $to = $theEmail;
  $subject = 'Renewables Toolbox App Password';
  $headers = "From: BC_ROR_Decision_Support_Tool" . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
  $message = '<html><body>';
  $message .= '<img src="http://renewablestoolbox.ca/img/rorlogo.png" alt="BC ROR Decision Support Tool" height="42" width="42"><h4>Hi, '.$theFName.'</h4><p> Your Password is: '.$thePass.'</body></html>';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Mail is sending and even the `<img alt="BC ROR Decision Support Tool">` tag is showing up in console mark up but there is no graphic showing!

Comment: does it show on other email systems? doesn't gmail block images unless you tell it not to?

Comment: Hi Gagon, it is working perfectly on `yahoo` mail but not on Gmail

Comment: Actually, you are right Gmail was blocking the image! is there any way to do this through PHP (I mean Un blocking the image in the Gamil)

Comment: no you can't force gMail or an other email application in to showing our images (and that is a good thing)